# Text Search in the database mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, full-text-search

I performed text search like this:

```
Post.find( { $text: { $search: "hello" } }) 
      .then(products => console.log(products))
      .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

It is finding the object that has text "Hello World" but not "hello3".
I want it to output Hello World and hello3.
How can I do that in mongoose?
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex search like:

```
db.collectionname.find({message:new RegExp( 'hello' , 'i')})
```

and you can use `.trim()` for your query search value :)

Comment: I have a doubt what does message mean here?

Comment: it means the object u search for what ever it's name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think text index can do this. You may want to try $regex search. Something like below

```
db.collectionname.find({"message": {"$regex" :"Hello.*",$options: 'i'} })
```

Comment: Can u please please tell me what does $options: 'i' mean?I am new to mongoose.

Comment: case insensitive search. In your example you need it as one the word is Hello and other is hello.

Comment: But here it will search only in message attribute right?

Comment: Yes that's the first part in find statement